# anxious to do something/anxious about doing/anxious doing

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Anxious** has two meaning: 1 be excited 2 be nervous, stressed about something

How can one know when it is implied the 1 or the 2 meaning? For example

> 1 I was anxious to meet her. (was I excited or nervous?)
>
> 2 I was anxious about meeting her. (was I excited or nervous?)
>
> 3 I was anxious meeting her. (was I excited or nervous?)

Answer (score 2):

If you're ***anxious to** [do something]*, that means you ***want*** to do it ***as soon as possible***. There's no implication of being nervous abut doing it - you're actually ***keen** to do it*. It usually (but not always) implies "excitement"; what's *always* implied is ***a sense of urgency***.

But if you're ***anxious about** [doing something]*, you're nervously anticipating something that you have to do (which quite possibly you're ***reluctant*** to do, but you have no choice).

---

With no preposition, as in OP's third example, or, say, *I was anxious **when** meeting her*, the second meaning always applies. Offhand I can't think of a context where the ***keen*** sense applies without preposition ***to***, but I stand to be corrected on that point.

Comment: We are very anxious that you come to see us. = KEEN?

Comment: I guessed there *would* be cases where the "keen" sense applies without preposition ***to***, but at the time I wrote that I was probably only thinking about *alternative **prepositions***. A that- clause is a completely different kettle of fish, where the "nervous / keen" distinction really turns on what makes sense. Your example almost inevitably conveys "keen", but that's obviously not the case with something like [*She was **anxious that she might fail...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anxious+that+she+might+fail%22)

Answer (score -1):

You would phrase them as if you were using the words *excited* or *nervous*:

- I was excited to meet her
- I was anxious to meet her
- I was nervous about meeting her
- I was anxious about meeting her

Comment: What about, "*I was **excited about** meeting her*"?